# Export all org-tables from batch mode

Tags: org-mode, org-table, batch-mode

How can I export all the tables in org-mode file similar to that.

```
* May
:PROPERTIES:
:TABLE_EXPORT_FILE: ~/Desktop/may.csv
:TABLE_EXPORT_FORMAT: orgtbl-to-csv
:END:

|One|Two|
|---+---|

* June
:PROPERTIES:
:TABLE_EXPORT_FILE: ~/Desktop/june.csv
:TABLE_EXPORT_FORMAT: orgtbl-to-csv
:END:

|One|Two|
|---+---|
```

I want to run something like this to export all tables to the defined file.

```
emacs --batch table.org  --eval 'org-table-export'
```

The problem is that I have to be in the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `org-table-map-tables` for iterating over the tables of an Org file.

Example for the Shell command:

```
emacs --batch table.org  --eval '(org-table-map-tables (quote org-table-export))'
```

You should give the file names for the exported tables and the export format in the org file like that:

```org
* First Section
:PROPERTIES:
:TABLE_EXPORT_FILE: first.csv
:TABLE_EXPORT_FORMAT: orgtbl-to-csv
:END:
| header 1 | header 2 |
|----------+----------|
|      1.1 |      1.2 |
|      2.1 |      2.2 |

* Second Section
:PROPERTIES:
:TABLE_EXPORT_FILE: second.csv
:TABLE_EXPORT_FORMAT: orgtbl-to-csv
:END:

| 2nd header 1 | 2nd header 2 |
|--------------+--------------|
|         21.1 |         21.2 |
|         22.1 |         22.2 |
```